# Creating a UIWebView from a JSContext block prevents assets from loading on iOS8

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, javascriptcore

I'm trying to create a webview from a JSContext block. However, it causes the new webview to load a webpage *without its assets (css/js)* which I think could be due to a conflict between the JSContext of the block, and the context of the webview.

Adding `dispatch_after` in the block - which delays the init of the webview and probably gets rid of the JS context - works perfectly.

```
let block: @objc_block (NSString!) -> Void = {
    (string : NSString!) -> Void in

    // This will produce a webview with the CSS that is not loading.
    // A solution is to dispatch_after the following code so it's executed outside of the JS callback.
    self.webview = UIWebView()
    self.webview.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(self.webview)
    self.webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!))

    /*
    // Working hack
    dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.webview = UIWebView()
        self.webview.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(self.webview)
        self.webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!))
    })
    */
}

let context = JSContext()
context.setObject(unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "test")

context.evaluateScript("test()")
```

Example project here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/13599/245679/ECTDF5dgHVfXr2P/JSContextWebViewConflictTest.zip

What's happening there?
Is there a way to make it work without the `dispatch_after` hack?